# Logging errors when an Elixir OTP Supervisor detects a crashed process

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp, erlang-supervisor

In the [Hex docs for Supervisor](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html#content), there is a line that states:

> A supervisor implemented using this module has a standard set of interface functions and includes functionality for tracing and error reporting.

Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to do this. What I would like is some kind of hook/notification/event that is fired when a `Supervisor` detects that a child worker has crashed and is being restarted. Mainly, I just want to log the fact that a worker crashed so I can display this error to the user, and in my case this requires writing the error message to a field in the database.

What am I missing? Is there somewhere I can pass a function or module that will be called when a child is terminated?

Answer (score 4):

Errors when children crash are logged to the SASL logger in BEAM and I think this is what the docs mean by "standard set of interface functions". See http://erlang.org/doc/apps/sasl/error_logging.html and http://erlang.org/doc/man/error_logger.html for some more details.

If you're using a `:simple_one_for_one` supervisor to start worker children and it's those you're interested in then you could consider monitoring them yourself rather than digging into the SASL stuff. e.g.

```
def MyApp.SomeModule do
  use GenServer

  # ... init etc.

  def start_worker() do
    {:ok, pid} = SomeWorkerSupervisor.start_child()
    Process.monitor(pid)
  end

  def handle_info(:'DOWN', _, _, worker_pid, reason) do
    # ... something
  end
end
```

The `reason` will be:

> Either the exit reason of the process, noproc (process or port did not exist at the time of monitor creation), or noconnection (no connection to the node where the monitored process resides).

(from http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#monitor-2)