# How to get notified for any crash from any linked process?

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp

I start multiple (genserver) process in my app though Supervisor, Dynamic supervisor, and sometime simply a direct start_link. Some of them can crash without letting me know when I start the app with `iex -S mix`. How to make sure I receive all the notification of any crash from any process, if I do not catch it myself? What are the good practice around "letting process crash" while keeping a trace of all the event?

```
XXX.start_link(ws_uri, __MODULE__, state, [{:name, MyModule}])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [GenServer docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#c:terminate/2):

> **terminate/2** is called if a callback (except init/1) does one of the following:
>
> -returns a :stop tuple
> -raises
> -calls Kernel.exit/1
> -returns an invalid value
> -the GenServer traps exits (using Process.flag/2) and the parent process sends an exit signal
>
> If part of a supervision tree, a GenServer will receive an exit signal
> when the tree is shutting down. The exit signal is based on the
> shutdown strategy in the child's specification,
> ...
> ...
> If the GenServer receives an exit signal (that is not :normal)
> from any process when it is not trapping exits it will exit abruptly
> with the same reason and so not call terminate/2. Note that a process
> does NOT trap exits by default and an exit signal is sent when a
> linked process exits or its node is disconnected.
>
> Therefore it is not guaranteed that terminate/2 is called when a
> GenServer exits. For such reasons, we usually recommend important
> clean-up rules to happen in separated processes either by use of
> monitoring or by links themselves. There is no cleanup needed when the
> GenServer controls a port (for example, :gen_tcp.socket) or
> File.io_device/0, because these will be closed on receiving a
> GenServer's exit signal and do not need to be closed manually in
> terminate/2.

Comment: Do you recommande me to implement terminate in all the module using GenServer and manually output the exception received?

Comment: @JeremyCochoy, Isn't that what you want to do?

Comment: @JeremyCochoy, For other options, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43372045/logging-errors-when-an-elixir-otp-supervisor-detects-a-crashed-process

Comment: One thousand thanks. I had a look to your link, then found about `SASL logger`, and then had a look at the elixir logger documentation, which allow loging everything by setting a simple flag. I wouldn't have found it without your help!

Answer (score 1):

The solution I ended up using, thanks to @7stud, is to activate SASL and OTP loggin in the Elixir logger.

If you use mix, you can add to your `config/config.exs` the lines:

```
config :logger,
  handle_otp_reports: true,
  handle_sasl_reports: true
```

For more information, see the [elixir logger documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/logger/Logger.html#module-erlang-otp-integration).

Comment: `:handle_otp_reports` is true by default, you do not need to set it by yourself.